# button event not calling the action method in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my mvc app the controller method is not at all calling ,im using script to call the method and im a newbie

```
     $('#submit_fourth').click(function () {

    alert('data sent');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Index",
        data: { 'Id': groupId },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            //do the necessary updations
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
    });
```

button event is

```
    <input class="send submit" type="submit" id="submit_fourth"  value="" />
```

and my action is

```
 public ActionResult Index(Models.Companyregister comreg)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            dataaccess.Companyregister_D ds = new dataaccess.Companyregister_D();

            int a = ds.insertcompanyregister(comreg);

                        }
        return View();
    }
```

and my qusetion is to how to pass the model to the controller method and how to call the controler method?   thanks in advadvances

Comment: add your button and action code..

Comment: finish putting button and action

Comment: @dazzlingkumar - See my answer below, note the type is 'POST' as you want to post the data and model needs to be converted into plain string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to pass the model to the controller method and how to call the
>   controler method?

You can send data in following way to controller action:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input class="send submit" type="submit" id="submit_fourth"  value="" />

<script>

    $('#submit_fourth').click(function() {

        alert('data sent');

        var model = { Name: "ABC Inc", UsedForYear: "2014" };
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: JSON.stringify(model)
            })
            .success(function(result) {
            });
    });

    </script>
```

**Controller.cs**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CompanyRegister companyregister)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Use the incoming data
        }

        return View();
    }
}

public class CompanyRegister
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UsedForYear { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the error alert is calling that is ths error function is calling

Comment: @dazzlingkumar - That mean the Ajax call is failing, make sure you have a action method decorated with HttpPost attribute AND it has an argument of type 'SomeClass' that has property name 'Maincompanyname'.

Comment: Put a breakpoint into controller action and see if breakpoint hit. If it does mean data binding happened successfully.

Comment: wow it is working the action method is calling ! thanks ji give ur mail id if you wish

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **GET** request, Ideally it should be **POST** request .

like -

```
 $('#submit_fourth').click(function () {
alert('data sent');
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Index",
    data: { 'Id': groupId },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        //do the necessary updations
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Change the Index Method type or create new as `[HTTPPOST]` as from script you are trying to call a `post` method.

**Solution 2:(I Prefer)**

Change the input type to `button` from `submit` to avoid multiple submit.

**Solution 3:**

Call Onclick function inside the html code like:
`<input type="submit" OnClick=DataSubmit(); />`

**Script**

```
<script>
DataSubmit()
{
    //Do your stuff;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must you want send youre model with ajax to action your action must has [HttpPost] and in your ajax call code add this

```
//Ajax Call inClient
$('#submit_fourth').click(function () {
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/CreateUser",
data: $('#formId').Serialize(),
type: 'POST',
success: function (result) {
    //To DO
}
});
});
// Model
public class User
{
 public string UserName { get; set; }
 public string Code{ get; set; }
}
// Action
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult CreateUser(User model)
   {
      return View();
   }
//View
@using (Html.BeginForm( new { Id= "form" }))
{
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })

      </div>
     </div>
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "form-control" })

      </div>
      </div>
<input type="button" id="submit_fourth"  value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your request type as 'POST',I think you want to insert some data so for this you have to call POST method & insert "HTTPPOST" annotation above your action method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.Companyregister comreg)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


        dataaccess.Companyregister_D ds = new dataaccess.Companyregister_D();

        int a = ds.insertcompanyregister(comreg);

                    }
   }
```